# I don't know how to use chars in C

Tags: c, string, char

I'm a beginner in programming so I've been making some mini projects.
I am trying to make a code that takes a string and returns one in which each character is repeated once and I'm getting an error and these signs (╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠).
Where am I going wrong?

```
    char str[20], fin[40];
    int i, j=0;

    gets(str);

    while (str[j] != '\0'){
        j++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < j; i++){
        fin[i*2-1] = str[i];
        fin[i*2] = str[i];
    }

    printf("%s\n", fin);

    return 0;
```

Comment: `fin[i*2-1]` What is the value of the array index when `i` is 0?

Comment: You're writing to `fin[-1]` and leaving the array without a proper zero terminator (`fin` has no `'\0'`).

Comment: Not the cause of your problem but still important to know: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: Which error do you get? What is the input What is the output you get? What is the expected output?

Comment: `╠` is 0xCC in CP437, which means [you're using uninitialized memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)

Comment: Thank you I corrected that but I still got these signs (╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠)

Comment: I type something and it should return ssoommeetthhiinngg, and it does but it also returns those signs and the word something at the end

Comment: because you don't properly terminate the string by putting a `'\0'` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

C does not have *strings*. *Strings*, in C, are a convention used by the compiler and the programmer and the Standard Library (and every library ever written). If you break the convention *strings* no longer "work" even though your code may be correct C code.

Depending on context, a *string* is a [part of an] **array of char** that contains a zero byte, or a **pointer** to such an array, like

```
char text[3] = {'h', 'i', '\0'}; // text is an array that contains the string "hi"
char *ptr = text;                // ptr points to the string "hi"
```

When you build your string character-by-character, remember the array elements start as *garbage*

```
char fin[20]; // fin is an array of 20 characters.
              // It is capable of holding string of up to 19 characters length
              // and the respective terminator
fin[0] = 'C'; // fin (the whole array) is not a string
fin[1] = '\0'; // fin now is the string "C" with the proper terminator (and a bunch of unused elements

fin[1] = ' '; // replaced the terminator with a space
              // fin is no longer a string
fin[2] = 'i';
fin[3] = 's'; // "C is############garbage########..." not a string
fin[4] = ' ';
fin[5] = 'f';
fin[6] = 'u';
fin[7] = 'n'; // "C is fun########garbage########..." not a string
fin[8] = '.'; // "C is fun.#######garbage########..." not a string
fin[9] = '\0'; // "C is fun." <== definitely a string
```

---

That's what you need to do. Add a `'\0'` at the end.